# Change Navigator backgroundColor globally

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The default Navigator and with this the App background is some light gray, around `#e4e3eb`.

Can I change this via the Navigator configuration (I use a StackNavigator)?

Note: I don't want to change the header backgroundColor, already did that via `headerStyle`.

Is there a comprehensive

Comment: so what do you want to change? what have you tried?

Comment: I want to change the default gray background of  the Navigator and make it white. Have tried to assign many different props to StackNavigators `navigationOptions` and now I'm asking if this is even possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kind of late to the question, but yes, you can change the background of the Stack Navigator card using the `cardStyle` option attribute.

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator( {
  s1: {screen:screen1},
  s2: {screen:screen2},
  s3: {screen:screen3},
  s4: {screen:screen4},
},{
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#FFFF00'},
      headerTintColor:'white',
      gesturesEnabled:false
    },
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'white'
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use defaultNavigationOptions instead of navigationOptions :

```
const globalNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    screen1: screen1,
    screen2: screen2,
}, 
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: () => ({
        cardStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
        },
    }),
    headerMode: "none",
})
```

Answer (score 3):

For create-react-native-app TypeScript version, the cardStyle would go into the options of the screen item. Below is an example for a product page :

```
(...)
const ProductsStack = createStackNavigator<TabOneParamList>();

function TabOneNavigator() {
  return (
    <ProductsStack.Navigator>
      <ProductsStack.Screen
        name="ProductsScreen"
        component={ProductsScreen}
        options={{
          cardStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'white',
          }
        }}
      />
    </ProductsStack.Navigator>
  );
}
(...)
```